# How to get resizing of UILabel objects with constraints to animate smoothly?

Tags: ios, uilabel, uianimation, ios-animations

I have a vertical rectangle -- a simple UIView -- that is divided into 4 sections, sort of like a pie chart, and each section will grow and shrink dynamically (as data rolls in), and I'm trying to get that to happen smoothly. Am using constraints to keep their sides united tightly to one another.

Part of the animation happens smoothly, but initially the four colored sections, which are just empty UILabel objects, are resized abruptly, revealing the background color of the container and then the animation seems to kick in and resolve the boundaries of the UILabel objects smoothly. I have a good video captured from the Simulator that shows the behavior, but don't have a way to provide that in the question here. Link perhaps coming later. The animation code right now is very simple.  When a timer fires I simply alternate between two different states wherein I assign the constant value for the height constraints. Like so:

```
-(void)relayoutSubviewsAnimated {

    static int ctr = 1;

    [self layoutIfNeeded];
    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5
            animations:^{
        
                if (ctr == 1) {
                    self->_outletBucketMastersHeight.constant = 0.25 * nHeightOfPieBar;
                    self->_outletBucketMeetsHeight.constant = 0.25 * nHeightOfPieBar;
                    self->_outletBucketApproachesHeight.constant = 0.25 * nHeightOfPieBar;
                    self->_outletBucketDidNotMeetHeight.constant = 0.25 * nHeightOfPieBar;
                    ctr++;
                }
                else if (ctr == 2) {
                    self->_outletBucketMastersHeight.constant = 0.2 * nHeightOfPieBar;
                    self->_outletBucketMeetsHeight.constant = 0.1 * nHeightOfPieBar;
                    self->_outletBucketApproachesHeight.constant = 0.4 * nHeightOfPieBar;
                    self->_outletBucketDidNotMeetHeight.constant = 0.4 * nHeightOfPieBar;
                    ctr = 1;
                }

                [self layoutIfNeeded];
            }];
}
```

So, initially the sections will resize suddenly, with no animation, and will momentarily look like so:

[image]

but will then smoothly animate the sizes until everything looks correct, like so:

[image]

The other usual constraints (horizontal and vertical space constraints) bind the UILabel objects to each other and leading and trailing constraints bind the UILabel objects to the sides of their container.

What could I be doing wrong?  How do I smoothly animate the growth and shrinkage of these 4 UILabels without the white background of the container suddenly showing through? I have read a number of SO questions and other articles.

Comment: Update the constraints before the animation. Only call `layoutIfNeeded` in the animation block. BTW - why use UILabel for the colored rectangles? Why not use plain UIView instances?

Comment: Wow - that is what I would definitely call a **bug**. If a `UILabel` height constraint is **smaller** it will not animate. Are you using `UILabel` because they will eventually have text? If not, using `UIView` will solve the issue. If the labels *will* have text, I think you'll need to embed them in `UIView`s.

Comment: @HangarRash, I tried putting the constraint assignments outside the animation block before I asked the question.  No effect.  Just tried it again to be sure.  I am using UILabel objects because I will eventually have text in them.

Comment: I am not sure what is meant by "embed" the UILabel in the UIView.  I used Interface Builder to drop them into the UIView, so they are properly "embedded" already I guess.  I will try to use UIView objects instead.  If it works, perhaps I can add UILabels to the UIViews for the text.

Comment: @Alyoshak - yes... I meant for each "segment" embed a `UILabel` centered vertically in a `UIView`

Comment: Using UIView instead of UILabel fixed the problem.  I admit I am surprised at this. No jerkily resized UILabel objects in the initial moment of animation.  I suppose I can figure out how to add a UILabel to each UIView and get the text representation I need. This is crazy.  A UILabel is just as a UIView with enhancements, as you know.

Comment: @DonMag, why don't you enter your suggestion as an answer and I will mark it as correct, for others later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments, this is what I would call a **BUG**.

When we animate the height of a `UILabel`:

- if it's getting taller, no problem
- if it's getting shorter, it **snaps** to the shorter height

Quick demonstration:

```
class V1_LabelHeightAnimVC: UIViewController {
    
    let testLabel = UILabel()
    let testView = UIView()
    
    let embeddedLabelView = UIView()
    
    var tlh: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var tvh: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var elvh: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        testLabel.text = "ABC"
        testLabel.textColor = .yellow
        testLabel.textAlignment = .center
        
        testView.backgroundColor = .red
        testLabel.backgroundColor = .blue
        
        testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        testLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(testView)
        view.addSubview(testLabel)
        
        let v = UILabel()
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        v.text = "ABC"
        embeddedLabelView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        embeddedLabelView.addSubview(v)
        
        embeddedLabelView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(embeddedLabelView)
        
        tvh = testView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0)
        tlh = testLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0)
        elvh = embeddedLabelView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            testView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            testView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            testView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0),
            
            testLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            testLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.trailingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            testLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0),
            
            v.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: embeddedLabelView.centerXAnchor),
            v.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: embeddedLabelView.centerYAnchor),
            
            embeddedLabelView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            embeddedLabelView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            embeddedLabelView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0),
            
            tvh, tlh, elvh,
            
        ])
        
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        
        tvh.constant = tvh.constant == 300.0 ? 100.0 : 300.0
        tlh.constant = tlh.constant == 300.0 ? 100.0 : 300.0
        elvh.constant = elvh.constant == 300.0 ? 100.0 : 300.0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
        
    }
}
```

It looks like this when running:

[image]

Tapping anywhere will toggle the Height constraint constants between 300 and 100 and animate to the new values.

- the Red rectangle is a `UIView` ... it animates as expected
- the dark Blue rectangle is a `UILabel` ... you'll see it snap
- the light Blue rectangle is a `UIView` with a `UILabel` as a subview. It gives us the desired animations.

Here's an example to achieve your layout, using a simple `UIView` subclass to hold the "centered" labels:

```
class EmbeddedLabelView: UIView {
    
    var text: String = "" {
        didSet {
            label.text = text
        }
    }
    
    let label = UILabel()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(label)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor),
        ])
    }
}
```

and an example controller:

```
class V2_LabelHeightAnimVC: UIViewController {
    
    let container = UIView()
    
    var heightConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
    
    let testLabel = UILabel()
    let testView = UIView()
    
    var tlh: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var tvh: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    var pcts: [[CGFloat]] = [
        [25, 25, 25, 25],
        [20, 10, 40, 30],
        [10, 50, 30, 20],
        [15, 15, 40, 30],
    ]
    var idx: Int = 0

    let infoLabel = UILabel()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        let colors: [UIColor] = [
            .init(red: 1.0, green: 0.8, blue: 0.8, alpha: 1.0),
            .init(red: 0.8, green: 1.0, blue: 0.8, alpha: 1.0),
            .init(red: 0.8, green: 0.8, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0),
            .init(red: 0.9, green: 0.9, blue: 0.6, alpha: 1.0),
        ]
        
        var prevView: UIView!
        
        for i in 0..<colors.count {
            
            let label = EmbeddedLabelView()
            label.backgroundColor = colors[i]
            label.text = "\(Int(pcts[0][i]))"
            
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            container.addSubview(label)
            
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor),
                label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor),
                label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0),
            ])
            
            if i == 0 {
                label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.topAnchor).isActive = true
            } else {
                label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: prevView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            }
            if i == colors.count - 1 {
                label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            }
            
            prevView = label
            
            let c = label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.25)
            c.priority = .defaultHigh
            heightConstraints.append(c)
        }
        
        heightConstraints.removeLast()
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(heightConstraints)
        
        container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(container)
        
        let instructionLabel = UILabel()
        
        instructionLabel.text = "\nTap to change the percentages:"
        
        [instructionLabel, infoLabel].forEach { v in
            v.font = .monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .light)
            v.numberOfLines = 0
        }
        
        let vStack = UIStackView()
        vStack.axis = .vertical
        vStack.spacing = 12
        vStack.alignment = .center
        vStack.backgroundColor = .init(red: 0.90, green: 0.90, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        
        [instructionLabel, infoLabel].forEach { v in
            vStack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
        
        vStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(vStack)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            container.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            container.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),

            vStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            vStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            vStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            vStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
            
        ])
        
        updateInfo()

    }
    
    func updateInfo() {
        var s: String = "\n"
        for i in 0..<pcts.count {
            s += "\(pcts[i])"
            if i == idx % pcts.count {
                s += " <--"
            }
            s += "\n"
        }
        infoLabel.text = s
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(heightConstraints)
        heightConstraints = []
        
        idx += 1
        updateInfo()
        
        let newPcts = pcts[idx % pcts.count]
        
        for i in 0..<newPcts.count {
            let p = newPcts[i] / 100.0
            let v = container.subviews[i]
            if i < newPcts.count - 1 {
                let c = v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.heightAnchor, multiplier: p)
                heightConstraints.append(c)
            }
            if let vv = v as? EmbeddedLabelView {
                vv.text = "\(Int(newPcts[i]))"
            }
        }
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(self.heightConstraints)
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
        
    }
}
```

That looks like this:

[image]

Each tap will cycle to the next set of percentages.

---

**Edit** - *because I hate answering an Obj-C question with Swift code...*

Here is a similar implementation as above, with a few "enhancements."

- EmbeddedLabelView class
- LabelBarsView class
- Values are translated into percentages of the sum, so...

  - if we pass `[1, 1, 1, 1]` each bar height will be `25%`
  - if we pass `[5, 10, 15, 20]` the bar heights will be `10%, 20% 30%, 40%`

**EmbeddedLabelView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
@interface EmbeddedLabelView : UIView
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *text;
@end
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

**EmbeddedLabelView.m**

```
#import "EmbeddedLabelView.h"

@interface EmbeddedLabelView ()
{
    UILabel *label;
}
@end

@implementation EmbeddedLabelView

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)commonInit {
    label = [UILabel new];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self addSubview:label];
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        // constrain all 4 sides
        [label.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topAnchor constant:0.0],
        [label.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.leadingAnchor constant:0.0],
        [label.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.trailingAnchor constant:0.0],
        [label.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.bottomAnchor constant:0.0],
    ]];
}

- (void)setText:(NSString *)text {
    label.text = text;
    _text = text;
}

@end
```

**LabelBarsView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
@interface LabelBarsView : UIView
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray <UIColor *>*colors;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray <NSNumber *>*values;
@end
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

**LabelBarsView.m**

```
#import "LabelBarsView.h"
#import "EmbeddedLabelView.h"

@interface LabelBarsView ()
{
    NSMutableArray <NSLayoutConstraint *>*heightConstraints;
}

@end

@implementation LabelBarsView

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)commonInit {
    heightConstraints = [NSMutableArray new];
    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
}

- (void)setColors:(NSArray<UIColor *> *)colors {
    
    if (colors.count == self.subviews.count) {
        // we're just changing the bar background colors
        for (int i = 0; i < colors.count; i++) {
            self.subviews[i].backgroundColor = colors[i];
        }
        return;
    }

    // we're either setting colors for the first time, or
    //  changing the number of bars
    
    for (UIView *v in self.subviews) {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }
    heightConstraints = [NSMutableArray new];
    EmbeddedLabelView *prevView;
    NSLayoutConstraint *c;
    float m = 1.0 / colors.count;
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.count; i++) {
        EmbeddedLabelView *v = [EmbeddedLabelView new];
        v.backgroundColor = colors[i];
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self addSubview:v];
        
        [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
            [v.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.leadingAnchor constant:0.0],
            [v.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.trailingAnchor constant:0.0],
        ]];
        
        if (!prevView) {
            [v.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topAnchor].active = YES;
        } else {
            [v.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:prevView.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
        }
        if (i == colors.count - 1) {
            [v.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
        }
        
        prevView = v;
        
        c = [v.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.heightAnchor multiplier:m];
        [heightConstraints addObject:c];
    }
    // to avoid auto-layout complaints with fractional constraints
    //  we don't use Height constraint on bottom bar/view
    //  it will "fill" the remaining space
    [heightConstraints removeLastObject];

    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:heightConstraints];
    
    _colors = colors;
    
}

- (void)setValues:(NSArray<NSNumber *> *)values {
    
    if (values.count != self.subviews.count) {
        // must send the same number of values as bars
        return;
    }
    
    // convert values to percentages
    float sum = [[values valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"] floatValue];
    
    [NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:heightConstraints];
    heightConstraints = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.count; i++) {
        EmbeddedLabelView *v = self.subviews[i];
        CGFloat p = [values[i] floatValue];
        v.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (unsigned long)p];
        NSLayoutConstraint *c = [v.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.heightAnchor multiplier:p / sum];
        [heightConstraints addObject:c];
    }
    // to avoid auto-layout complaints with fractional constraints
    //  we don't use Height constraint on bottom bar/view
    //  it will "fill" the remaining space
    [heightConstraints removeLastObject];
    
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:heightConstraints];
    
    _values = values;
    
}

@end
```

**LabelBarsViewController.h**

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
@interface LabelBarsViewController : UIViewController
@end
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

**LabelBarsViewController.m**

```
#import "LabelBarsViewController.h"
#import "LabelBarsView.h"

@interface LabelBarsViewController ()
{
    LabelBarsView *barsView;
    NSArray <NSArray *>*someValues;
    NSInteger valIDX;
    UILabel *infoLabel;
}
@end

@implementation LabelBarsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    // some sample values
    someValues = @[
        @[@1, @1, @1, @1],
        @[@1, @2, @3, @4],
        @[@4, @3, @2, @1],
        @[@5, @10, @15, @20],
        @[@20, @10, @40, @30],
        @[@350, @120, @500, @280],
        @[@10, @50, @30, @20],
        @[@15, @15, @40, @30],
    ];
    
    NSArray *colors = @[
        [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.9 blue:0.9 alpha:1.0],
        [UIColor colorWithRed:0.6 green:1.0 blue:0.6 alpha:1.0],
        [UIColor colorWithRed:0.8 green:0.9 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0],
        [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.9 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0],
    ];
    
    barsView = [LabelBarsView new];
    [barsView setColors:colors];

    barsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:barsView];

    UILabel *instructionLabel = [UILabel new];
    instructionLabel.font = [UIFont monospacedSystemFontOfSize:14.0 weight:UIFontWeightLight];
    instructionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    instructionLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    instructionLabel.text = @"Tap to cycle through value sets...";

    instructionLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:instructionLabel];
    
    infoLabel = [UILabel new];
    infoLabel.font = [UIFont monospacedSystemFontOfSize:14.0 weight:UIFontWeightLight];
    infoLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    
    infoLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:infoLabel];
    
    UILayoutGuide *g = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide;
    
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        
        [barsView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.topAnchor constant:20.0],
        [barsView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.leadingAnchor constant:20.0],
        [barsView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.bottomAnchor constant:-20.0],
        [barsView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:80.0],
        
        [instructionLabel.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.topAnchor constant:40.0],
        [instructionLabel.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:barsView.trailingAnchor constant:20.0],
        [instructionLabel.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.trailingAnchor constant:-20.0],
        
        [infoLabel.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:instructionLabel.bottomAnchor constant:20.0],
        [infoLabel.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:barsView.trailingAnchor constant:20.0],
        [infoLabel.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.trailingAnchor constant:-20.0],
        
    ]];
    
    valIDX = -1;
    [self nextValues];
}

- (void) nextValues {
    ++valIDX;
    [self updateInfo];
    [barsView setValues:someValues[valIDX % someValues.count]];
}

- (void) updateInfo {
    NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString new];
    for (int i = 0; i < someValues.count; i++) {
        [s appendString:(i == valIDX % someValues.count ? @"--> [" : @"    [")];
        for (int j = 0; j < someValues[i].count; j++) {
            [s appendFormat:@"%@", someValues[i][j]];
            if (j < someValues[i].count - 1) {
                [s appendString:@", "];
            }
        }
        [s appendString:@"]"];
        [s appendString:@"\n"];
    }
    infoLabel.text = s;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self nextValues];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}

@end
```

Looks like this when running - each tap cycles to the next values set:

[image] [image]

Comment: Thanks.  Now that's what I call a helpful answer.  I will award extra points for this if I can.  I've read of other people doing that but don't know how.  Wait for the bounty period to expire?

Comment: @Alyoshak - Whoops -- I meant to do this in Objective-C, but it's almost dinner time and I wanted to post it quickly :) Pretty much identical though. As far as "extra points" ... yeah, I have seen people add a Bounty after the answer has been accepted - don't know if it gets automatically applied when the period expires or if there's another step.

Comment: @Alyoshak - see the **Edit** to my answer. I did a (very) similar implementation in Obj-C with some minor enhancements.

Comment: Thanks. Excellent. I'll get to it Monday.