# How to make UIImage fully opaque so that nothing shows through from the background?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, transparency, alpha

I have a UIImageView that I am making a child view of a larger UILabel, using addSubview:.  Part of the image (a PNG -- using UIImage) has a transparent background and part of it does not.  This is because the image is a circle and I want any background that is outside the circle to show through and be visible. But I want the circular image itself to be drawn over everything. Yet what I am getting looks like this:

[image]

Notice that the border from the rectangle of the parent view shows through even though the circle's green inside is drawn over the grey background. I want none of the UILabel's rectangular border to be showing through the circle.

Perhaps this is a problem with my image.  I used the Paintbrush app on MacOS to modify a png that I had, but I'm not good at image editing. I have UIImageView's alpha set to 1.0 and opaque set to YES. I construct and add the UIImageView as a subview to the UILabel like this:

```
NSArray *subViews = [self subviews];
for (UIView *view in subViews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        UILabel *lblPad = (UILabel*)view;
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(lblPad.frame.size.width - 14, -11, 25, 25);
        UIImageView *badge = [self constructBadge:frame];
        [lblPad addSubview:badge];
    }
}

-(UIImageView*)constructBadge:(CGRect)frameIn
{    
    UIImageView *ivRet = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_check_circle_mod2.png"]];
    ivRet.frame = frameIn;
    ivRet.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [ivRet setAlpha:1.0];
    [ivRet setOpaque:YES];

    return ivRet;
}
```

The png image I am using is:

[image]

Another I have tried which behaves the same is here:

[image]

How to fix this?

**[EDIT -- NEW DEVELOPMENT]**

I discovered that one line of code is directly related to, perhaps causing, this. I am setting a border around each UILabel on the view, with the following code:

```
NSArray *subViews = [self subviews];
self.dictAllLabels = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (UIView *view in subViews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        UILabel *lblPad = (UILabel*)view;
        CALayer *layer = [lblPad layer];
        //[layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor]];
    }
}
```

If I comment out the setBorderWidth: call the circular image appears correctly.  If I uncomment it out the problem occurs. So my question should have been, "Why does changing the border width on the CALayer of the label make the subview semi-transparent?"

Comment: Clearly your circle image is translucent or this could not happen. So either fix your circle image or put an opaque circle view right behind it.

Comment: Or maybe the label is translucent? A view added as a subview to a translucent superview will itself be translucent.

Comment: Thx. The Label is not translucent.

Comment: Well then the first thing I said stands.

Comment: Your responses have been helpful.  I've just not been able to figure out what, if anything, is wrong with the image, whether somehow the solid-looking parts of the png are actually semi-transparent or not. Perhaps this question isn't one for Stack Overflow. Has to be a way to tell what is wrong with the image. Transparent pixels only appear to be outside of the circle.

Comment: Can you post the circle image file somewhere?

Comment: Just added the pic(s).

Comment: OK, so I definitely agree that those are not translucent inside the circle. So can you actually show some real code instead of just a snippet? Help me reproduce the problem you're having.

Comment: Just figured out an important piece of this puzzle.  Wow. Edited the question to explain.

Comment: Please don't be so stingy with the code. There is still no code that actually shows the circle view being added to the label. Remember I want to reproduce this. I can't guess your code. And I shouldn't have to. Show me how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Code added.  Sorry.

Comment: I'm still scratching my head over this one actually. You found this unexpected. I found it unexpected. That's 100% of participants so far! You might file a bug report just to see whether Apple responds. Seem like maybe they are doing some sort of optimization in the drawing that causes this, and I've no idea how long that's been going on. It _could_ go all the way back to iOS 4 for all I know; this isn't something I've ever tested before. But on the other hand it could be relatively new behavior. I mean, whose border is it anyway?

Comment: Good question. Whose border is it? Strangely I just uncovered a bug recently in UILabel the previous question I asked. The guy that responded to my question said "Wow - that is what I would definitely call a bug."  https://stackoverflow.com/a/75264547/343178  I've been doing this a while, but never uncovered bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have explained the source of the issue perfectly! The problem, however, is not that the circle image view is transparent. The problem is that the border is effectively front of it. That's because of the relationship between the circle view, as a subview of the label, and the border drawing. And *that* is because a subview of a view is a sublayer of that view's layer.

The solution is simply to make the circle image view *not* a subview of the label.

```
CGRect labFrame = lblPad.frame;
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(
    labFrame.origin.x + labFrame.size.width - 14, 
    labFrame.origin.y - 11, 
    25,
    25
);
UIImageView *badge = [self constructBadge:frame];
[self addSubview:badge];
```